# Has Array#sort become stable?

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

From the [docs](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.0.0/Array.html#method-i-sort)

"When the block returns zero, the order for a and b is indeterminate, and may be unstable:

```
a = 'abcde'.split('').shuffle
a # => ["e", "b", "d", "a", "c"]
a1 = a.sort {|a, b| 0 }
a1 # =>  ["c", "e", "b", "d", "a"]
```

"

If I run this code the sort appears to be stable:

```
puts RUBY_VERSION # => 3.0.3
p a = 'abcde'.split('').shuffle  # => ["d", "e", "c", "b", "a"]
p a1 = a.sort {|a, b| 0 } # => ["d", "e", "c", "b", "a"]
```

Has Ruby sneakily got a stable sort?

Comment: I think it might depends on a definition of "stable". Assuming that `stable` means that it behaves as a function, returning always the same output for the same input, then it is depends on what we understand as input for `sort`. If we say that input is an array, then yes - it seems pretty stable. However, if we say that input are elements of that aray, than it's not as the output will depend on the order of those elements - `array.shuffle.sort` is not guaranteed to return the same array on each run.

But clearly, the example in the doc does not work any more! :)

Comment: According to the docs, `sort` is not guaranteed to be stable, although of course a particular Ruby installation may provide a stable implementation. If you want to ensure stability, you better write your own implementation (we did this for our project).

Comment: @BroiSatse "stable" means that equal elements keep their relative positions.

Comment: Just checked the source code and Ruby (YARV) seems to depend entirely on [`qsort`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort) so it's up to their implementation. On some platforms it might be stable, and on others it's unstable. Ruby can't guarantee anything and that's probably what the comment in the docs is all about.

Comment: @Stefan You should probably post that as an answer.